# Parallel.For() with Interlocked.CompareExchange(): poorer performance and slightly different results to serial version

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, mean, interlocked

I experimented with calculating the mean of a list using `Parallel.For()`. I decided against it as it is about four times slower than a simple serial version. Yet I am intrigued by the fact that it does not yield exactly the same result as the serial one and I thought it would be instructive to learn why.

My code is:

```
public static double Mean(this IList<double> list)
{
        double sum = 0.0;


        Parallel.For(0, list.Count, i => {
                        double initialSum;
                        double incrementedSum;
                        SpinWait spinWait = new SpinWait();

                        // Try incrementing the sum until the loop finds the initial sum unchanged so that it can safely replace it with the incremented one.
                        while (true) {
                            initialSum = sum;
                            incrementedSum = initialSum + list[i];
                            if (initialSum == Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sum, incrementedSum, initialSum)) break;
                            spinWait.SpinOnce();
                        }
                     });

        return sum / list.Count;
    }
```

When I run the code on a random sequence of 2000000 points, I get results that are different in the last 2 digits to the serial mean.

I searched stackoverflow and found this: [VB.NET running sum in nested loop inside Parallel.for Synclock loses information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606811/vb-net-running-sum-in-nested-loop-inside-parallel-for-synclock-loses-information). My case, however, is different to the one described there. There a thread-local variable `temp` is the cause of inaccuracy, but I use a single sum that is updated (I hope) according to the textbook `Interlocked.CompareExchange()` pattern. The question is of course moot because of the poor performance (which surprises me, but I am aware of the overhead), yet I am curious whether there is something to be learnt from this case.

Your thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: What you expect? You look tons of compare exchange operations doing nothing. Not healthy.

Comment: Floating-point addition is not associative. You cannot simply parallelize a sequential sum and expect the same result. I don't see how your particular case is supposed to be different from the linked question at all -- that a partial sum happens to compare (not) equal is still no guarantee the final outcome will be the same, because (and this is the fundamental issue) you are still rearranging the order of the terms.

Comment: @TomTom: You’re right, but the question is the difference in value.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: First I wanted to say they tested associativity and I tested commutativity, but on second thoughts, you’re right. Associativity is always involved as the previous sum represents a grouping that is different upon each run. Thank you for your insights and sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: It isn't a dumb question; it's very useful to see why this doesn't work. If you need exact results and your range isn't too great, use `decimal`. And rather than cobbling together your own addition, you can leverage parallel LINQ: `list.AsParallel().Sum()`.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I did learn something useful thanks to you. I tried the LINQ version and it shows the same difference. As for performance, LINQ is about 2-3 times slower than the serial upon first run then 2-3 times faster upon subsequent runs.

Comment: @tethered.sun The first run of the code is often slower for a number of reasons.  When testing speed always run a few iterations (or a few hundred if you have the time) to allow JIT and so on to work, then take your time readings.  PLINQ's `Sum` is certainly faster than the standard LINQ `Sum` in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using *double* is the underlying problem, you can feel better about the synchronization not being the cause by using *long* instead.  The results you got are in fact correct but that never makes a programmer happy.

You discovered that floating point math is communicative but [not associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).  Or in other words, `a + b == b + a` but `a + b + c != a + c + b`.  Implicit in your code that the order in which the numbers are added is quite random.

[This C++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa) talks about it as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel quite a bit ashamed for having failed to recognise that the case I did manage to find is actually the same as mine, but I learnt much from the comments. Please bear with me; I am a mere physicist and a self-taught amateur at programming at best. But I love to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy issue is very well addressed in the other answers so I won't repeat it here, other that to say never trust the low bits of your floating point values.  Instead I'll try to explain the performance hit you're seeing and how to avoid it.

Since you haven't shown your sequential code, I'll assume the absolute simplest case:

```
double sum = list.Sum();
```

This is a very simple operation that should work about as fast as it is possible to go on one CPU core.  With a very large list it seems like it should be possible to leverage multiple cores to sum the list.  And, as it turns out, you can:

```
double sum = list.AsParallel().Sum();
```

A few runs of this on my laptop (i3 with 2 cores/4 logical procs) yields a speedup of about 2.6 times over multiple runs against 2 million random numbers (same list, multiple runs).

Your code however is much, much slower than the simple case above.  Instead of simply breaking the list into blocks that are summed independently and then summing the results you are introducing all sorts of blocking and waiting in order to have all of the threads update a single running sum.

Those extra waits, the much more complex code that supports them, creating objects and adding more work for the garbage collector all contribute to a much slower result.  Not only are you wasting a whole lot of time on each item in the list but you are essentially forcing the program to do a sequential operation by making it wait for the other threads to leave the `sum` variable alone long enough for you to update it.

Assuming that the operation you are actually performing is more complex than a simple `Sum()` can handle, you may find that the `Aggregate()` method is more useful to you than `Parallel.For`.

There are several overloads of the `Aggregate` extension, including one that is effectively a [Map Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28parallel_pattern%29) implementation, with similarities to how bigdata systems like MapReduce work.  Documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383667%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

This version of `Aggregate` uses an accumulator seed (the starting value for each thread) and three functions:

1. `updateAccumulatorFunc` is called for each item in the sequence and returns an updated accumulator value
2. `combineAccumulatorsFunc` is used to combine the accumulators from each partition (thread) in your parallel enumerable
3. `resultSelector` selects the final output value from the accumulated result.

A parallel sum using this method looks something like this:

```
double sum = list.AsParallel().Aggregate(
    // seed value for accumulators
    (double)0, 
    // add val to accumulator
    (acc, val) => acc + val,
    // add accumulators
    (acc1, acc2) => acc1 + acc2,
    // just return the final accumulator
    acc => acc
);
```

For simple aggregations that works fine.  For a more complex aggregate that uses an accumulator that is non-trivial there is a [variant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384149%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that accepts a function that creates accumulators for the initial state.  This is useful for example in an `Average` implementation:

```
public class avg_acc
{
    public int count;
    public double sum;
}

public double ParallelAverage(IEnumerable<double> list)
{
    double avg = list.AsParallel().Aggregate(
        // accumulator factory method, called once per thread:
        () => new avg_acc { count = 0, sum = 0 },
        // update count and sum
        (acc, val) => { acc.count++; acc.sum += val; return acc; },
        // combine accumulators
        (ac1, ac2) => new avg_acc { count = ac1.count + ac2.count, sum = ac1.sum + ac2.sum },
        // calculate average
        acc => acc.sum / acc.count
    );
    return avg;
}
```

While not as fast as the standard `Average` extension (~1.5 times faster than sequential, 1.6 times slower than parallel) this shows how you can do quite complex operations in parallel without having to lock outputs or wait on other threads to stop messing with them, and how to use a complex accumulator to hold intermediate results.

Comment: Again I am astonished to see how my poor question has attracted such quality answers. Thank you very much. As I told earlier, I am a physicist and lack formal training. Though I am beginning to use LINQ more frequently, I was not aware of utilities like `AsParallel` or `Aggregate()`, which seem promising for a multitude of tasks. Thank you for your time.